# Looking for javascript/ajax autocomplete function, *Not jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

Google turns up a lot of crappy code in this area. I'm looking for a solid cross-browser autocomplete script with standard keyboard functionality: up, down, tab, enter, escape. The script must not utilize jquery (My widget could be used on sites already implementing jquery and I don't want to handle double loading or version conflicts). The script must be able to accept updates to the autocomplete list. (I'm pulling results from my database on user update). Thanks! -- skibulk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concerned about conflicting with existing jquery, then just include a check for jquery at the beginning of the code.

```
if (!jQuery) {
   ...load jquery...
}
```

Comment: What if another module is loaded after mine, with yet another jQuery? Other developers may not run the check.

Comment: Since your need appears to be for events that would occur AFTER the dom is loaded, that should not be an issue.

Comment: You could also do the check in the window.loaded event

Answer (score 1):

1.- Have a db with common terms and have an API to access the most common one(Increment each word each time a query is made)

2.- Query it every time the input changes. Split(' ') it and select [-1] the last "incomplete" word and put the autocomplete as the background. When the user presses tab change the last word for the autocomplete.

Really, I don't know what you have as backend or to which extend you want to take it.